# how to get text from a strong element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following elements and need to get the text value of the strong element in which the input checkbox is selected

```
<input class="inputCheckbox" tpye="checkbox"><strong>Testing</strong>
```

I tired this but not working..

```
$(".inputCheckbox input:checked strong").text();
```

Comment: simple typo, flagged to close

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have misspelled the word type.

```
<input class="inputCheckbox" type="checkbox"><strong>Testing</strong>
```

You can try,

```
$(".inputCheckbox input:checked").parent().find("strong").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `strong` element is not inside of the `input` element, but next to it. You have a couple of options here. The easiest is to give the `strong` element a classname or id. The other option is to use siblings as suggested by undefined.

Answer (score -1):

To find `strong` element like this

```
<p>Hello How are you <strong>Chandan </strong></p>
```

try this:

```
$(this).find("strong").text();
```

output:

> Chandan